# WinRT information: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

Tags: windows-store-apps, mvvmcross

When i use IMvxmessenger i get an exception that says  An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code  WinRT information: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.  Additional information: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information in your question it's very hard to add much real advice.

Clearly you are using a message from the messenger to access something that is thread critical.

MvvmCross and WinRT both provide ways to marshal method calls on to specific threads - e.g. there are several different `Subscribe` methods provided by the messenger to allow you to specify context - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#messenger

> The three different options for subscribing for messages differ only in terms of which thread messages will be passed back on:
>
> - Subscribe - messages will be passed directly on the Publish thread. These subscriptions have the lowest processing overhead - messages will always be received synchronously whenever they are published. You should use this type of subscription if you already know which type of thread the Publish will be called on and if you have a good understanding on the resource and UI usage of your message handler.
> - SubscribeOnMainThread - any message published on a background thread will be marshalled to the main UI thread. This type of subscription is ideal if your message handler needs to perform some resource-unintensive task which involves interacting with the UI.
> - SubscribeOnThreadPoolThread - messages will always be queued for thread pool processing. This always involves an asynchonous post - even if the message is published on an existing ThreadPool thread. This type of subscription is ideal if your message handler needs to perform some resource-intensive task as it won't block the UI, nor the message publisher.